# Reverse Order Of Integer By Recursion

Tags: c, algorithm

> "Write a recursive function that get an integer as an input (that does not start with 0) and return the integer in reverse order.
>
> For example: 58347 return as 74385
>
> Pointers, arrays, memory allocation is not allowed"
>
> int reverse(int num);

We must know the "length" of the integer, can it be done without a global variable?

Maybe some bitwise operations?

My try:

```
int reverse(int num){
    int temp;
    if(num/10 == 0)
        return num;
    else
      return num%10*10+reverse(num=/10)
}
```

Comment: Length is not needed. All you need is simple decimal integer arithmetic (more specifically division and modulo with `10`).

Comment: decimal representation, we get 1234 and return 4321

Comment: Why not give it a try, post some code, and we'll help you solve any problems you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (that does not start with 0)

I am not sure what the problem is trying to imply here, given the function prototype provided.

> We must know the "length" of the integer

No, there is no need to know the length of the integer.

> can it be done without a global variable?

Yes, of course. You are supposed to get the units of the integer (i.e. the digit of smallest value, e.g. `4` in `1234`), extract it (e.g. getting `123`) and keep recursing until the number is `0`.

> Maybe some bitwise operations?

No, division (`/`) and modulo (`%`).

Comment: But I need to return the reverse number as an int, how can I save the "pieces" I get after each modulo?

Comment: Typically, you code the recursion as another function (so that you may have as many parameters as needed to save the "pieces"), and the original function would call that recursive function with the right initial setup.

Answer (score 1):

I won't do your homework for you but I will give you some hints:

1. The operation `n % 10` will give you the least significant digit in an integer's base-10 representation.
2. With integer division, the condition `n /= 10` in a loop will always eventually be false (`0`), and will change the least-significant digit in the base-10 representation of a number to the second least-significant digit.
3. Multiplying an accumulator variable by 10 will create "room" for another digit.

Comment: 3 is what I meant in "We must know the "length" of the integer"

Comment: @gbox Nope, none of what I wrote implies that you need to know the length of the integer beforehand.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on 3, ok I see we count the number of calls to the function

Comment: You get the next digit out of the int you want to reverse. You're storing it in the (eventual) return value. To add this digit to the number, multiply it by 10 first, then add the new digit.

Comment: So if we have 123 we get 30 and then 20 and then 1

Comment: You'd have 3 first, then you'd have 30 + 2 (32), then you'd have 320, then 321

Comment: So we use 2 functions? I can not see how you got to 30+2

Comment: I feel like going any further in this explanation would cross the line from "giving you hints" to "doing your homework for you".